# MiKTeX can't find stix2 font files

Tags: fonts, luatex, miktex, unicode-math, stix

I want to use the `stix2` fonts together with `unocode-math`. I was trying to load them as in the MWE below, which works fine with TeX Live, but fails with MiKTeX, telling me `The font "STIX2Text-Regular" cannot be found.`, etc.
I've installed MiKTeX as admin and the `stix2-otf` package is installed.

What's the issue here? How can I fix it?

Is this the recommended way of loading the fonts or is there a safer way?

---

```latex
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[
  math-style=ISO,
  partial=upright,
  warnings-off={mathtools-overbracket, mathtools-colon},
  ]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{STIX2Text}[
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic,
    ItalicFeatures = { SmallCapsFont = *-Italic },
    SlantedFont = *-Regular,
    SlantedFeatures= { FakeSlant=0.2 },
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    BoldFeatures = { SmallCapsFont = *-Bold },
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
    BoldItalicFeatures = { SmallCapsFont = *-BoldItalic },
    BoldSlantedFont= *-Bold,
    BoldSlantedFeatures= { FakeSlant=0.2, SmallCapsFont = *-Bold },
    SmallCapsFont = *-Regular,
    SmallCapsFeatures={ RawFeature=+smcp },
    Extension = .otf
  ]
\setmathfont{STIX2Math}

\begin{document}

Hello World!

\end{document}
```

Here's the start of the log file.

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.0 (MiKTeX 21.1) (format=lualatex 2021.1.21)  21 JAN 2021 11:00
 restricted system commands enabled.
**test02.tex
(./test02.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
Lua module: luaotfload 2021-01-08 3.17 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2020-12-30 2.73 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2020-12-30 2.73 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/wilde/AppData/Local/MiKTeX
/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2021-01-07.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2021-01-07.
lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 2
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 0x1.8e76c8b439581p+1
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' at position 1 in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 3
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/wilde/AppData/Local/MiKTeX
/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_truetype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' at position 1 in `post_linebreak_filt
er'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' at position 2 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' at position 1 in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' at position 1 in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' at position 1 in `glyph_info'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
. L3 programming layer <2021-01-09> xparse <2020-03-03>
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/article.cls"
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from C:/Users/wilde/AppData/Local/M
iKTeX/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc)
\c@part=\count173
\c@section=\count174
\c@subsection=\count175
\c@subsubsection=\count176
\c@paragraph=\count177
\c@subparagraph=\count178
\c@figure=\count179
\c@table=\count180
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty"
Package: expl3 2021-01-09 L3 programming layer (loader) 

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def"
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2021-01-09 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count181
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box47
))
Package: xparse 2020-10-27 L3 Experimental document command parser

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generic.tex"))
Package: fontspec 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Lua module: fontspec 2020/02/21 2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty"
Package: fontspec-luatex 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaT
eX
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count182
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count183
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count184
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count185
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count186
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count187
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count188
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count189
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count190
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count191
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count192
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen139
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen140
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen141

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg")))
(C:/Users/wilde/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.sty
Package: unicode-math 2020/01/31 v0.8q Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

(C:/Users/wilde/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-luat
ex.sty
Package: unicode-math-luatex 2020/01/31 v0.8q Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaL
aTeX
 ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty"
Package: l3keys2e 2020-10-27 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty"
Package: fix-cm 2015/01/14 v1.1t fixes to LaTeX

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def"
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding TS1 on input line 47.
))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty"
Package: amsmath 2020/09/23 v2.17i AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip49

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks15
\ex@=\dimen142
))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty"
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen143
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty"
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count193
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 236.
\uproot@=\count194
\leftroot@=\count195
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count196
\DOTSCASE@=\count197
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box48
\strutbox@=\box49
\big@size=\dimen144
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count198
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count199
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count266
\dspbrk@lvl=\count267
\tag@help=\toks16
\row@=\count268
\column@=\count269
\maxfields@=\count270
\andhelp@=\toks17
\eqnshift@=\dimen145
\alignsep@=\dimen146
\tagshift@=\dimen147
\tagwidth@=\dimen148
\totwidth@=\dimen149
\lineht@=\dimen150
\@envbody=\toks18
\multlinegap=\skip50
\multlinetaggap=\skip51
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks19
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2923.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2924.
)
(C:/Users/wilde/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/tex/lualatex/lualatex-math/lualatex-math
.sty
Package: lualatex-math 2020/09/25 v1.9 Patches for mathematics typesetting with
 LuaLaTeX
 ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty"
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count271
)
Lua module: lualatex-math 2013/08/03 1.3 Patches for mathematics typesetting wit
h LuaLaTeX)
\g__um_fam_int=\count272
\g__um_fonts_used_int=\count273
\l__um_primecount_int=\count274
\g__um_primekern_muskip=\muskip17

(C:/Users/wilde/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-tabl
e.tex)))
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: File not foun
d: "STIX2Text-Regular.otf".

! Package fontspec Error: The font "STIX2Text-Regular" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.26   ]
      

A font might not be found for many reasons.
 Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc.

 When in doubt, ask someone for help!


luaotfload | aux : no font with id 0
luaotfload | aux : no font with id 0

! Package fontspec Error: The font "STIX2Text-Regular" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.26   ]
      

A font might not be found for many reasons.
 Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc.

 When in doubt, ask someone for help!



! Package fontspec Error: The font "STIX2Text-Regular" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.26   ]
      

A font might not be found for many reasons.
 Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc.

 When in doubt, ask someone for help!



[...]
```

Comment: I use TeXLive2020 (actually, MacTeX2020), and I can replicate the issue you've encountered. However, all is well if I write either `\setmainfont{Stix Two Text}[<options>]` and `\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}` or `\setmainfont{StixTwoText}[<options>]` and `\setmathfont{StixTwoMath}`. I think the main issue is that you need to write `Two` rather than `2` in the font name declarations.

Comment: @Mico Oh! That indeed seems to be the issue: The font files have different names in MiKTeX than in TeX Live. Why though??

Comment: Note that I run MacTeX (a fraternal twin to TeXLive), not MikTeX. I think the otf font file names have always included `Two` rather than `2`; it's the `stix2` *package* that obscures this fact.

Comment: @Mico They should be (according to CTAN), but in my TeX Live installation they are called `STIX2Text-Regular.otf`, etc. (As well as missing the `Medium` and `SemiBold` variants.)

Comment: Which version of TeXLive is installed on your system? (If it's not TeXLive2020, it may be time to upgrade...) I see from the log file you posted that your MikTeX distribution is very much up to date.

Comment: @Mico It is TeX Live 2020 and it isn't that long ago that I updated. But another update just now did fix the issue (i.e. the font files now have the same name as on CTAN). Curious. This must have been a recent change to TeX Live (or all of `stix2`)..

Comment: I've posted short answer to summarize the gist of the preceding comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main issue is that the otf font file names contain the string "Two" rather than the numeral "2".

On my system (MacTeX2020, all updates applied) both of the following variants work fine:

```
\setmainfont{Stix Two Text}[<options>] 
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}
```

and

```
\setmainfont{StixTwoText}[<options>]
\setmathfont{StixTwoMath}
```

For sure, though, `\setmainfont{Stix2Text}[<options>]` and `\setmathfont{Stix2Math}` do *not* work.