# miktex does not find STIX2Math.otf font

Tags: miktex, fontspec, miktex-update

latest updated MiKTex does return:

```
e:\miktex-portable\texmfs\data\miktex\log\miktex-maketfm.log
! Font TU/STIX2Math.otf(1)/m/n/12=[STIX2Math.otf]/OT at 12.0pt not loadable: Me
tric (TFM) file or installed font not found.
```

I was using \usepackage[stixtwo]{fontsetup} in the preamble of my document. Is this a MiKTeX bug that needs to be reported or is it a problem of the fontsetup package maintainer? A MWE is here:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage[stixtwo]{fontsetup}
\usepackage{geometry} % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{a4paper} % or letterpaper (US) or a5paper or....
\usepackage{graphicx} % support the \includegraphics command and options

\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: how should one be able to test without a complete example?

Comment: Might this be a clash between `2` and `two` like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579822/miktex-cant-find-stix2-font-files (though there `two` was said to be right so this looks like to be OK here).

Comment: `\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}` should work regardless of whether you have `STIX2Math.otf` or `STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf` on your box.

Answer (score 1):

The font file has been renamed to STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf recently. I guess the package `fontsetup` should be updated. (I cannot comment due to low reputation, so I post this as answer.)